# Update AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment to Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Elastic Beanstalk claims support for Python 3.6 but only 3.4 is offered in the dropdown when I try to update my (existing) Python-based environment's configuration. If it helps, I'm in region eu-west-1. What am I missing?

Comment: not getting your question...

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk release notes clearly mentions Python 3.6: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/relnotes/release-2018-09-25-linux.html

i try however to change my config via the UI and no 3.6 option is offered.

Clearer?

Comment: do one thing connect to your ec2 ...using SSH and install setup simple...

Comment: @asplake, from the table it appears that Python 3.6 support is still not available in eu-west-1.